# Password field hidden option in html

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, html5-canvas

For my HTML password textbox, I have used **input type** as password but I am able to see what is being typed as password input. **In any case we shouldn't be able to see what we type in a password input.**

Can anyone suggest me how can I fix this issue? Try my below code , copy in a .TXT file and save as .HTML and open this HTML in Firefox or IE to replicate the issue.

**Here is my problematic code:**

```
<htm l>
    <form id="login" method="post" action="index.html">
    <div style="width: 450px; height: 250px; background: blue;BORDER=8"><br/><br/><br/>
    &nbsp;<strong>Username: </strong>&nbsp; <input type="text" name="userid" size="18" maxlength="18"/><br/>&nbsp;<br/>
    &nbsp;<strong>Password : </strong> &nbsp; <input type="password " name="pswrd" size="18" maxlength="18"/>&nbsp;<br/><br/><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp 
    &nbsp;</div><br/><br/></html>
```

Comment: remove the space in your type="password"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the space behind password after type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a extra space in `type="password"`

```
<input type="password" name="pswrd" size="18" maxlength="18"/>
```

Remove it. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space in 
    type="password "
So, it should be
    type="password"

If html does not understand any type like "password " then it assumes that element is type text